# How to only select rows where one column is unique and the other is a certain value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out which ids only have one type of transaction.

I have tried joining and selecting distinct but I am doing it wrong

```
select transactions.type, id 
from datasource
group by id, transactions.type
```

This gives me a table with two transaction types: either dep or withdraw. Most IDs have two rows, one being dep and the other withdraw. I want to select only the ids that have only the withdraw transaction type

Comment: Your query is going to generate errors.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

use where condition and `not exists`

```
select transactions.type, id from datasource t1
where type='withdraw'
and not exists( select 1 from datasource t2 where t1.id=t2.id
               and type='dep')
```

Comment: Thank you but this will also select the ids that have the transaction type of deposit. It wont show that type but the ids shown from that query will be ones that have that type. Does that make sense? Sorry if my question was not clear

Comment: @ChasePinkerton answer edited due lack of description it was unclear in your question that's why i answered on that way now check

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` with `having count(*)=1` clause

```
select id 
  from datasource 
 where transactions_type in     
    (
     select transactions_type, id 
       from datasource
      group by transactions_type
     having count(*)=1 )
```

Since "You are trying to figure out which ids only have one type of transaction"

If you specifically look for `transactions_type = 'withdraw'`, then add `and transactions_type = 'withdraw'` to the end of the above Select Statement.

P.S. I suppose there's a type for `transactions.type`, and that should be `transactions_type`, isn't that?

Answer (score 0):

I think aggregation does what you want.  However, I am confused what your data structure is.  A `join` is needed somewhere:

```
select ds.id, min(t.type)
from datasource ds join
     transactions t
     on ds.? = t.?   -- what is the join key?
group by ds.id
having min(t.type) = max(t.type);
```

If `transactions.type` is actually a column in `datasource`, then:

```
select ds.id, min("transactions.type")
from datasource ds 
group by ds.id
having min("transactions.type") = max("transactions.type");
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, but simpler:

```
select id, count(distinct transactions.type)
from datasource
group by id
having count(distinct transactions.type) = 1
```

It is unclear, however, what transactions.type is. It doesn't appear to be valid as a column name. Or did you mean to write `transactions_type`?